# SAS to Python Conversion using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, sas

I'm migrating SAS code to Python and came across this piece of code which I migrated but not sure if its the right way. Can someone let me know if there is a better solution out there.
I'm using Pandas (0.24.2) [system restriction] to hold the data but version is not a barrier.

SAS:

```
  if A < 50 and B < 10000 then do;
     if B > 75 and C > 52 then final = 10;
     else final = 2;
  end;
  else if A < 500 and B < 20000 then do;
     if D < 150000 then do;
         if B > 750 and C > 52 then final = 10;
         else final = 2;
     end;
     else if D < 600000 then do;
         if B > 3000 and C > 52 then final = 30;
         else final = 10;
     end;
  end;
  else if A < 7000 then do;
      if D < 40000 then do;
          if B > 200 and C > 52 then final = 10;
          else final = 2;
      end;
      else if D < 200000 then do;
          if B > 1000 and C > 52 then final = 30;
          else final = 10;
      end;
  end;
  else if A < 30000 then do;
      if D < 10000 then do;
          if B > 50 and C > 52 then final = 10;
          else final = 2;
      end;
      else if D < 100000 then do;
          if B > 500 and C > 52 then final = 30;
          else final = 10;
      end;
  end;
  else if D < 1000 then final = 10;
```

Python:

```
df['final'] = np.where((df['A'] < 50) & (df['B'] < 10000), 
                       np.where((df['B'] > 75) & (df['C'] > 52), 10, 2), 
                       np.where((df['A'] < 500) & (df['B'] < 20000),
                                np.where(df['D'] < 150000, 
                                         np.where((df['B'] > 750) & (df['C'] > 52), 10, 2),
                                         np.where(df['D'] < 600000, 
                                                  np.where((df['B'] > 3000) & (df['C'] > 52), 30, 10), 
                                                  df['final'])),
                                np.where((df['A'] < 7000), 
                                          np.where(df['D'] < 40000, 
                                                   np.where((df['B'] > 200) & (df['C'] > 52), 10, 2),
                                                   np.where(df['D'] < 200000, 
                                                            np.where((df['B'] > 1000) & (df['C'] > 52), 30, 10), 
                                                            df['final'])),
                                          np.where(df['A'] < 30000, 
                                                   np.where(df['D'] < 40000, 
                                                            np.where((df['B'] > 50) & (df['C'] > 52), 10, 2),
                                                            np.where(df['D'] < 100000, 
                                                                     np.where((df['B'] > 500) & (df['C'] > 52), 30, 10), 
                                                                     df['final'])),
                                                   np.where(df['D'] < 1000, 10, df['final']))))
```

Comment: well **final** has three possible values {2,10,30}.  I would look at simplifying binary logic to get to a much simpler binary logic....

Comment: But since the conditions are unique, i'll still end up writing all conditions